# With query string Scroll To Div Not Working Properly

Tags: html, jquery, scroll

Without query string scroll to div is like below.

http://localhost/#solutions

With query string scroll to div like below.

http://localhost/#solutions/?lang=fr

What is the right way to scroll to div With query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the issue. By adding below URL. Now it's working.

http://localhost/?lang=fr#solutions